# How to validate password length in wordpress

Tags: plugins, menus, wp-login-form

How to make password length validation in the below code as i am new to php 
I want user to set atleast 8 character length password.
Pass1 is the id of password.I tried to use below code but its not giving any error on validation

```
    public static function plugin_activated() {
        // Information needed for creating the plugin's pages
        $page_definitions = array(
            'member-login' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Sign In', 'personalize-login' ),
                'content' => '[custom-login-form]'
            ),
            'member-account' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Your Account', 'personalize-login' ),
                'content' => '[account-info]'
            ),
            'member-register' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Register', 'personalize-login' ),
                'content' => '[custom-register-form]'
            ),
            'member-password-lost' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Forgot Your Password?', 'personalize-login' ),
                'content' => '[custom-password-lost-form]'
            ),
            'member-password-reset' => array(
                'title' => __( 'Pick a New Password', 'personalize-login' ),
                'content' => '[custom-password-reset-form]'
            )
        );

        foreach ( $page_definitions as $slug => $page ) {
            // Check that the page doesn't exist already
            $query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=' . $slug );
            if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
                // Add the page using the data from the array above
                wp_insert_post(
                    array(
                        'post_content'   => $page['content'],
                        'post_name'      => $slug,
                        'post_title'     => $page['title'],
                        'post_status'    => 'publish',
                        'post_type'      => 'page',
                        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
                        'comment_status' => 'closed',
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }

    //
    // REDIRECT FUNCTIONS
    //

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the custom login page instead of wp-login.php.
     */
    public function redirect_to_custom_login() {
        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $this->redirect_logged_in_user();
                exit;
            }

            // The rest are redirected to the login page
            $login_url = home_url( 'member-login' );
            if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
                $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', $_REQUEST['redirect_to'], $login_url );
            }

            if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['checkemail'] ) ) {
                $login_url = add_query_arg( 'checkemail', $_REQUEST['checkemail'], $login_url );
            }

            wp_redirect( $login_url );
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user after authentication if there were any errors.
     *
     * @param Wp_User|Wp_Error  $user       The signed in user, or the errors that have occurred during login.
     * @param string            $username   The user name used to log in.
     * @param string            $password   The password used to log in.
     *
     * @return Wp_User|Wp_Error The logged in user, or error information if there were errors.
     */
    public function maybe_redirect_at_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ) {
        // Check if the earlier authenticate filter (most likely,
        // the default WordPress authentication) functions have found errors
        if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {
            if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
                $error_codes = join( ',', $user->get_error_codes() );

                $login_url = home_url( 'member-login' );
                $login_url = add_query_arg( 'login', $error_codes, $login_url );

                wp_redirect( $login_url );
                exit;
            }
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the URL to which the user should be redirected after the (successful) login.
     *
     * @param string           $redirect_to           The redirect destination URL.
     * @param string           $requested_redirect_to The requested redirect destination URL passed as a parameter.
     * @param WP_User|WP_Error $user                  WP_User object if login was successful, WP_Error object otherwise.
     *
     * @return string Redirect URL
     */
    public function redirect_after_login( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {
        $redirect_url = home_url();

        if ( ! isset( $user->ID ) ) {
            return $redirect_url;
        }

        if ( user_can( $user, 'manage_options' ) ) {
            // Use the redirect_to parameter if one is set, otherwise redirect to admin dashboard.
            if ( $requested_redirect_to == '' ) {
                $redirect_url = admin_url();
            } else {
                $redirect_url = $redirect_to;
            }
        } else {
            // Non-admin users always go to their account page after login
            $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-account' );
        }

        return wp_validate_redirect( $redirect_url, home_url() );
    }


    public function redirect_after_logout() {
        $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-login?logged_out=true' );
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }

    public function redirect_to_custom_register() {
        if ( 'GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $this->redirect_logged_in_user();
            } else {
                wp_redirect( home_url( 'member-register' ) );
            }
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Redirects the user to the custom "Forgot your password?" page instead of
     * wp-login.php?action=lostpassword.
     */
    public function redirect_to_custom_lostpassword() {
        if ( 'GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $this->redirect_logged_in_user();
                exit;
            }

            wp_redirect( home_url( 'member-password-lost' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Redirects to the custom password reset page, or the login page
     * if there are errors.
     */
    public function redirect_to_custom_password_reset() {
        if ( 'GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
            // Verify key / login combo
            $user = check_password_reset_key( $_REQUEST['key'], $_REQUEST['login'] );
            if ( ! $user || is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
                if ( $user && $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' ) {
                    wp_redirect( home_url( 'member-login?login=expiredkey' ) );
                } else {
                    wp_redirect( home_url( 'member-login?login=invalidkey' ) );
                }
                exit;
            }

            $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-password-reset' );
            $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'login', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['login'] ), $redirect_url );
            $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'key', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['key'] ), $redirect_url );

            wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
            exit;
        }
    }


    //
    // FORM RENDERING SHORTCODES
    //

    /**
     * A shortcode for rendering the login form.
     *
     * @param  array   $attributes  Shortcode attributes.
     * @param  string  $content     The text content for shortcode. Not used.
     *
     * @return string  The shortcode output
     */
    public function render_login_form( $attributes, $content = null ) {
        // Parse shortcode attributes
        $default_attributes = array( 'show_title' => false );
        $attributes = shortcode_atts( $default_attributes, $attributes );

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return __( 'You are already signed in.', 'personalize-login' );
        }

        // Pass the redirect parameter to the WordPress login functionality: by default,
        // don't specify a redirect, but if a valid redirect URL has been passed as
        // request parameter, use it.
        $attributes['redirect'] = '';
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
            $attributes['redirect'] = wp_validate_redirect( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'], $attributes['redirect'] );
        }

        // Error messages
        $errors = array();
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['login'] ) ) {
            $error_codes = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['login'] );

            foreach ( $error_codes as $code ) {
                $errors []= $this->get_error_message( $code );
            }
        }
        $attributes['errors'] = $errors;

        // Check if user just logged out
        $attributes['logged_out'] = isset( $_REQUEST['logged_out'] ) && $_REQUEST['logged_out'] == true;

        // Check if the user just registered
        $attributes['registered'] = isset( $_REQUEST['registered'] );

        // Check if the user just requested a new password
        $attributes['lost_password_sent'] = isset( $_REQUEST['checkemail'] ) && $_REQUEST['checkemail'] == 'confirm';

        // Check if user just updated password
        $attributes['password_updated'] = isset( $_REQUEST['password'] ) && $_REQUEST['password'] == 'changed';

        // Render the login form using an external template
        return $this->get_template_html( 'login_form', $attributes );
    }

    /**
     * A shortcode for rendering the new user registration form.
     *
     * @param  array   $attributes  Shortcode attributes.
     * @param  string  $content     The text content for shortcode. Not used.
     *
     * @return string  The shortcode output
     */
    public function render_register_form( $attributes, $content = null ) {
        // Parse shortcode attributes
        $default_attributes = array( 'show_title' => false );
        $attributes = shortcode_atts( $default_attributes, $attributes );

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return __( 'You are already signed in.', 'personalize-login' );
        } elseif ( ! get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) {
            return __( 'Registering new users is currently not allowed.', 'personalize-login' );
        } else {
            // Retrieve possible errors from request parameters
            $attributes['errors'] = array();
            if ( isset( $_REQUEST['register-errors'] ) ) {
                $error_codes = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['register-errors'] );

                foreach ( $error_codes as $error_code ) {
                    $attributes['errors'] []= $this->get_error_message( $error_code );
                }
            }

            // Retrieve recaptcha key
            $attributes['recaptcha_site_key'] = get_option( 'personalize-login-recaptcha-site-key', null );

            return $this->get_template_html( 'register_form', $attributes );
        }
    }

    /**
     * A shortcode for rendering the form used to initiate the password reset.
     *
     * @param  array   $attributes  Shortcode attributes.
     * @param  string  $content     The text content for shortcode. Not used.
     *
     * @return string  The shortcode output
     */
    public function render_password_lost_form( $attributes, $content = null ) {
        // Parse shortcode attributes
        $default_attributes = array( 'show_title' => false );
        $attributes = shortcode_atts( $default_attributes, $attributes );

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return __( 'You are already signed in.', 'personalize-login' );
        } else {
            // Retrieve possible errors from request parameters
            $attributes['errors'] = array();
            if ( isset( $_REQUEST['errors'] ) ) {
                $error_codes = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['errors'] );

                foreach ( $error_codes as $error_code ) {
                    $attributes['errors'] []= $this->get_error_message( $error_code );
                }
            }

            return $this->get_template_html( 'password_lost_form', $attributes );
        }
    }

    /**
     * A shortcode for rendering the form used to reset a user's password.
     *
     * @param  array   $attributes  Shortcode attributes.
     * @param  string  $content     The text content for shortcode. Not used.
     *
     * @return string  The shortcode output
     */
    public function render_password_reset_form( $attributes, $content = null ) {
        // Parse shortcode attributes
        $default_attributes = array( 'show_title' => false );
        $attributes = shortcode_atts( $default_attributes, $attributes );

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return __( 'You are already signed in.', 'personalize-login' );
        } else {
            if ( isset( $_REQUEST['login'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['key'] ) ) {
                $attributes['login'] = $_REQUEST['login'];
                $attributes['key'] = $_REQUEST['key'];

                // Error messages
                $errors = array();
                if ( isset( $_REQUEST['error'] ) ) {
                    $error_codes = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['error'] );

                    foreach ( $error_codes as $code ) {
                        $errors []= $this->get_error_message( $code );
                    }
                }
                $attributes['errors'] = $errors;

                return $this->get_template_html( 'password_reset_form', $attributes );
            } else {
                return __( 'Invalid password reset link.', 'personalize-login' );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * An action function used to include the reCAPTCHA JavaScript file
     * at the end of the page.
     */
    public function add_captcha_js_to_footer() {
        echo "<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'></script>";
    }

    /**
     * Renders the contents of the given template to a string and returns it.
     *
     * @param string $template_name The name of the template to render (without .php)
     * @param array  $attributes    The PHP variables for the template
     *
     * @return string               The contents of the template.
     */
    private function get_template_html( $template_name, $attributes = null ) {
        if ( ! $attributes ) {
            $attributes = array();
        }

        ob_start();

        do_action( 'personalize_login_before_' . $template_name );

        require( 'templates/' . $template_name . '.php');

        do_action( 'personalize_login_after_' . $template_name );

        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $html;
    }


    //
    // ACTION HANDLERS FOR FORMS IN FLOW
    //

    /**
     * Handles the registration of a new user.
     *
     * Used through the action hook "login_form_register" activated on wp-login.php
     * when accessed through the registration action.
     */
    public function do_register_user() {
        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
            $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-register' );

            if ( ! get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) {
                // Registration closed, display error
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'register-errors', 'closed', $redirect_url );
            } elseif ( ! $this->verify_recaptcha() ) {
                // Recaptcha check failed, display error
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'register-errors', 'captcha', $redirect_url );
            } else {
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $first_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name'] );
                $last_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['last_name'] );

                $result = $this->register_user( $email, $first_name, $last_name );

                if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
                    // Parse errors into a string and append as parameter to redirect
                    $errors = join( ',', $result->get_error_codes() );
                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'register-errors', $errors, $redirect_url );
                } else {
                    // Success, redirect to login page.
                    $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-login' );
                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'registered', $email, $redirect_url );
                }
            }

            wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initiates password reset.
     */
    public function do_password_lost() {
        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
            $errors = retrieve_password();
            if ( is_wp_error( $errors ) ) {
                // Errors found
                $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-password-lost' );
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'errors', join( ',', $errors->get_error_codes() ), $redirect_url );
            } else {
                // Email sent
                $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-login' );
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'checkemail', 'confirm', $redirect_url );
                if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
                    $redirect_url = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
                }
            }

            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the user's password if the password reset form was submitted.
     */
    public function do_password_reset() {
        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
            $rp_key = $_REQUEST['rp_key'];
            $rp_login = $_REQUEST['rp_login'];

            $user = check_password_reset_key( $rp_key, $rp_login );

            if ( ! $user || is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
                if ( $user && $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' ) {
                    wp_redirect( home_url( 'member-login?login=expiredkey' ) );
                } else {
                    wp_redirect( home_url( 'member-login?login=invalidkey' ) );
                }
                exit;
            }
            if ( strlen( $_POST['pass1'] ) < 3 )
            {
                //passwords so small
                    $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-password-reset' );
                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'error', 'password_reset_mismatch1', $redirect_url );
            }


            if ( isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
                if ( $_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2'] ) {
                    // Passwords don't match
                    $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-password-reset' );

                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'key', $rp_key, $redirect_url );
                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'login', $rp_login, $redirect_url );
                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'error', 'password_reset_mismatch', $redirect_url );

                    wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
                    exit;
                }

                if ( empty( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
                    // Password is empty
                    $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-password-reset' );

                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'key', $rp_key, $redirect_url );
                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'login', $rp_login, $redirect_url );
                    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'error', 'password_reset_empty', $redirect_url );

                    wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
                    exit;

                }

                // Parameter checks OK, reset password
                reset_password( $user, $_POST['pass1'] );
                wp_redirect( home_url( 'member-login?password=changed' ) );
            } else {
                echo "Invalid request.";
            }

            exit;
        }
    }


    //
    // OTHER CUSTOMIZATIONS
    //

    /**
     * Returns the message body for the password reset mail.
     * Called through the retrieve_password_message filter.
     *
     * @param string  $message    Default mail message.
     * @param string  $key        The activation key.
     * @param string  $user_login The username for the user.
     * @param WP_User $user_data  WP_User object.
     *
     * @return string   The mail message to send.
     */
    public function replace_retrieve_password_message( $message, $key, $user_login, $user_data ) {
        // Create new message
        $msg  = __( 'Hello!', 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $msg .= sprintf( __( 'You asked us to reset your password for your account using the email address %s.', 'personalize-login' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $msg .= __( "If this was a mistake, or you didn't ask for a password reset, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.", 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $msg .= __( 'To reset your password, visit the following address:', 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $msg .= site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user_login ), 'login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $msg .= __( 'Thanks!', 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n";

        return $msg;
    }


    //
    // HELPER FUNCTIONS
    //

    /**
     * Validates and then completes the new user signup process if all went well.
     *
     * @param string $email         The new user's email address
     * @param string $first_name    The new user's first name
     * @param string $last_name     The new user's last name
     *
     * @return int|WP_Error         The id of the user that was created, or error if failed.
     */
    private function register_user( $email, $first_name, $last_name ) {
        $errors = new WP_Error();

        // Email address is used as both username and email. It is also the only
        // parameter we need to validate
        if ( ! is_email( $email ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'email', $this->get_error_message( 'email' ) );
            return $errors;
        }

        if ( username_exists( $email ) || email_exists( $email ) ) {
            $errors->add( 'email_exists', $this->get_error_message( 'email_exists') );
            return $errors;
        }

        // Generate the password so that the subscriber will have to check email...
        $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );

        $user_data = array(
            'user_login'    => $email,
            'user_email'    => $email,
            'user_pass'     => $password,
            'first_name'    => $first_name,
            'last_name'     => $last_name,
            'nickname'      => $first_name,
        );

        $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
        wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $password );

        return $user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the reCAPTCHA parameter sent with the registration
     * request is valid.
     *
     * @return bool True if the CAPTCHA is OK, otherwise false.
     */
    private function verify_recaptcha() {
        // This field is set by the recaptcha widget if check is successful
        if ( isset ( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
            $captcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        // Verify the captcha response from Google
        $response = wp_remote_post(
            'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
            array(
                'body' => array(
                    'secret' => get_option( 'personalize-login-recaptcha-secret-key' ),
                    'response' => $captcha_response
                )
            )
        );

        $success = false;
        if ( $response && is_array( $response ) ) {
            $decoded_response = json_decode( $response['body'] );
            $success = $decoded_response->success;
        }

        return $success;
    }

    /**
     * Redirects the user to the correct page depending on whether he / she
     * is an admin or not.
     *
     * @param string $redirect_to   An optional redirect_to URL for admin users
     */
    private function redirect_logged_in_user( $redirect_to = null ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( user_can( $user, 'manage_options' ) ) {
            if ( $redirect_to ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
            } else {
                wp_redirect( admin_url() );
            }
        } else {
            wp_redirect( home_url( 'member-account' ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds and returns a matching error message for the given error code.
     *
     * @param string $error_code    The error code to look up.
     *
     * @return string               An error message.
     */
    private function get_error_message( $error_code ) {
        switch ( $error_code ) {
            // Login errors

            case 'empty_username':
                return __( 'You do have an email address, right?', 'personalize-login' );

            case 'empty_password':
                return __( 'You need to enter a password to login.', 'personalize-login' );

            case 'invalid_username':
                return __(
                    "We don't have any users with that email address. Maybe you used a different one when signing up?",
                    'personalize-login'
                );

            case 'incorrect_password':
                $err = __(
                    "The password you entered wasn't quite right. <a href='%s'>Did you forget your password</a>?",
                    'personalize-login'
                );
                return sprintf( $err, wp_lostpassword_url() );

            // Registration errors

            case 'email':
                return __( 'The email address you entered is not valid.', 'personalize-login' );

            case 'email_exists':
                return __( 'An account exists with this email address.', 'personalize-login' );

            case 'closed':
                return __( 'Registering new users is currently not allowed.', 'personalize-login' );

            case 'captcha':
                return __( 'The Google reCAPTCHA check failed. Are you a robot?', 'personalize-login' );

            // Lost password

            case 'empty_username':
                return __( 'You need to enter your email address to continue.', 'personalize-login' );

            case 'invalid_email':
            case 'invalidcombo':
                return __( 'There are no users registered with this email address.', 'personalize-login' );

            // Reset password

            case 'expiredkey':
            case 'invalidkey':
                return __( 'The password reset link you used is not valid anymore.', 'personalize-login' );

            case 'password_reset_mismatch':
                return __( "The two passwords you entered don't match.", 'personalize-login' );
                case 'password_reset_mismatch1':
                return __( "The two passwords you entered are short.", 'personalize-login' );
            case 'password_reset_mismatch1':
                 return("the password are two small");


            case 'password_reset_empty':
                return __( "Sorry, we don't accept empty passwords.", 'personalize-login' );

            default:
                break;
        }

        return __( 'An unknown error occurred. Please try again later.', 'personalize-login' );
    }


    //
    // PLUGIN SETUP
    //

    /**
     * Registers the settings fields needed by the plugin.
     */
    public function register_settings_fields() {
        // Create settings fields for the two keys used by reCAPTCHA
        register_setting( 'general', 'personalize-login-recaptcha-site-key' );
        register_setting( 'general', 'personalize-login-recaptcha-secret-key' );

        add_settings_field(
            'personalize-login-recaptcha-site-key',
            '<label for="personalize-login-recaptcha-site-key">' . __( 'reCAPTCHA site key' , 'personalize-login' ) . '</label>',
            array( $this, 'render_recaptcha_site_key_field' ),
            'general'
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'personalize-login-recaptcha-secret-key',
            '<label for="personalize-login-recaptcha-secret-key">' . __( 'reCAPTCHA secret key' , 'personalize-login' ) . '</label>',
            array( $this, 'render_recaptcha_secret_key_field' ),
            'general'
        );
    }

    public function render_recaptcha_site_key_field() {
        $value = get_option( 'personalize-login-recaptcha-site-key', '' );
        echo '<input type="text" id="personalize-login-recaptcha-site-key" name="personalize-login-recaptcha-site-key" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" />';
    }

    public function render_recaptcha_secret_key_field() {
        $value = get_option( 'personalize-login-recaptcha-secret-key', '' );
        echo '<input type="text" id="personalize-login-recaptcha-secret-key" name="personalize-login-recaptcha-secret-key" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" />';
    }

}

// Initialize the plugin
$personalize_login_pages_plugin = new Personalize_Login_Plugin();

// Create the custom pages at plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Personalize_Login_Plugin', 'plugin_activated' ) );
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to read through, which is notoriously hard. Including code is great, but please try to reduce examples to a minimum required to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Please try with [Minimum Password Strength](https://wordpress.org/plugins/minimum-password-strength/) plugin

Comment: You should edit your question and include just a simplified yet meaningful part of your code

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( strlen( $_POST['pass1'] ) < 3 )
{
   //passwords so small
   $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-password-reset' );
   $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'error', 'password_reset_mismatch1', $redirect_url );
}
```

I see here that you're checking if password length is less than 3. I guess you have to change `3` to `8`:

```
if ( strlen( $_POST['pass1'] ) <= 8 )
{
   //passwords so small
   $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-password-reset' );
   $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'error', 'password_reset_mismatch1', $redirect_url );
}
```

Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: i  also did the same but nothing works instead of 3 i use 8

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Make sure that in your register form template in HTML, your input `name` attribute is set to `pass1` and your form `method` is set to `POST`, like: `<form method='POST' action='/path/to/some/file'><input type='password' name='pass1'></form>`

Comment: name and id both are pass1

Comment: Look at my edited comment and check it out. Also check if `action` is pointing to right PHP file. The one you're validating password in